# Chart.js not updating after setInterval ( setInterval Not executing )

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js

i am drawing a chart using chart.js by reading the columns from csv file and trying to update the chart on setInterval because during that interval new data may have been added to the csv. but the chart isnt updating

i am printing (console.log to see if the setinterval is executed on timer ) but it seems like the setinterval only execute once as the console.log only print once ,

**here is the code simplified:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id='here'>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      const makeChart = async () => {
        const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        const csvData = await getData();
     console.log("log");
        const { dataLabels, columnFive, columnSix } = csvData;
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "line",
          data: {
            labels: dataLabels,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Long Lots",
                data: columnFive,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "green",
         pointRadius: 0,
              },
              {
                label: "Short Lots",
                data: columnSix,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "red",
        pointRadius: 0,
          gridLines: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
              },
            ],
          },
        });

      };



setInterval(makeChart.update, 0, console.log("updated"))



window.addEventListener('load', makeChart);
      const getData = async () => {
        const data = await fetch("./myfile.csv").then((res) => res.text());
        const dataLabels = [];
        const columnFive = [];
        const columnSix = [];
        const rows = data.split("\n");
        rows.map((row) => {
          const cols = row.split(",");
          dataLabels.push(cols[0]);
          columnFive.push(parseFloat(cols[5]));
          columnSix.push(parseFloat(cols[6]));
        });
        return { dataLabels, columnFive, columnSix };
      };
    </script>
 </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1 :**

tried to do what Yosef suggested but i am not sure if what i did is the correct way of doing it, I hink i didnt do it correctly since the chart is still not being updated:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id='here'>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
const myChart=0;
      const makeChart = async () => {
      const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        const csvData = await getData();
     console.log("log");
        const { dataLabels, columnFive, columnSix } = csvData;
     
      let myChart= new Chart(ctx, {
          type: "line",
          data: {
            labels: dataLabels,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Long Lots",
                data: columnFive,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "green",
         pointRadius: 0,
              },
              {
                label: "Short Lots",
                data: columnSix,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "red",
        pointRadius: 0,
          gridLines: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
              },
            ],
          },
        });   
      };

setInterval(myChart.update, 0, console.log("updated"))

window.addEventListener('load', makeChart);
      const getData = async () => {
        const data = await fetch("./myfile.csv").then((res) => res.text());
        const dataLabels = [];
        const columnFive = [];
        const columnSix = [];
        const rows = data.split("\n");
        rows.map((row) => {
          const cols = row.split(",");
          dataLabels.push(cols[0]);
          columnFive.push(parseFloat(cols[5]));
          columnSix.push(parseFloat(cols[6]));
        });
        return { dataLabels, columnFive, columnSix };
      };


    </script>
 </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see `makeChart.update` method defined anywhere ..?

Comment: You probably want to define `myChart` outside the locl scope and call `myChart.update` in the set interval. Probably start the interval after the chart initiated

Comment: okay @Teemu i thought that chart.update (from documentation is predefined function) thats why i tried to paste makechart.update as is 
i am still a noob so dont even know what i am doing

Comment: It's possible that the library contains that method, but you've explicitly defined `makeChart` as a function, and never added `update` method to that function.

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky thank you , but isnt there any other way? i have got it here after trying for days , and dont really know much about javascript

Comment: @teemu can you perhaps guide me on adding method ? i tried adding it but it so many errors pop up , and all the examples i could fine for this method are either for the ones that are not using the csv to begin with or others examples only use one dataset

Comment: Nope, do what Yosef told you, that's the correct solution.

Comment: I tried that , and updated the OP can you check if this is correct way ?